# Diels-Alder reaction question

Tags: pericyclic

In class, we learned that Diels-Alder reactions only occurs with s-cis conformations and that conformations like those in cyclopentadiene are permanently locked in a cis-transformation and that is why they are so reaction. We also learned that the reaction proceeds at a higher rate with an electro-withdrawing substituent (eg. carbonyl) . Why then is a molecule like the one in the figure not reactive while a similar structure, a cyclopentadienone, is?[image]

Comment: Whoa, carbonyl isn't a substituent here, but part of ring, which isn't a flat one... Also why do you even think it is or isn't reactive?

Comment: Compared to cyclopentadienone? Well, since both molecules have s-cis bonds, thats probably not it. Also, according to my textbook, carbonyl groups increase rxn rate because they are electron withdrawing due to resonance and both structures have resonance structures. Perhaps because cyclopentadienone has more ring strain? Im not really sure though cause I can't picture the structure of the molecule in the figure.

Comment: Actually, why would have a electron withdrawing carbonyl group and the fact that they produce resonance structures increase the rate of reaction?

Comment: Cycloundecapentaenon is so different and incomparable that I have no idea why you picked this compound.

Answer (score -1):

You need to draw this structure in a 3D visualizer program, eg, Avogadro. While this structure looks similar to cyclopentadiene, in 3D it looks vastly different.
[image]

Comment: Is that the all-cis isomer? One of the double bonds at the back looks like it’s trans to me.

Comment: You are correct. The all cis conformation does have the similar problem as well.

Comment: You should probably edit the image. (Btw, it’s configuration not conformation.)